How to format the creation timestamp of a ZFS snapshot with TrueNAS?
I would like to know the precise creation time of a ZFS snapshot. Note that I am not referring to the timestamp in the snapshot name itself but the result of querying the creation property when using zfs get creation mysnapshot
The default formatting only shows precision up to the minute:
root@truenas[~]# zfs get creation tank1/home@auto-hourly-20240717T180000:0200
NAME                                         PROPERTY  VALUE                  SOURCE
tank1/home@auto-hourly-20240717T180000:0200  creation  Wed Jul 17 18:00 2024  -

As we can see in this example, it displays Wed Jul 17 18:00 2024.
Is there a way to display the seconds? Or to fully configure the datetime format (e.g. ISO 8601)?

This can be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

The use of argument -p (Display numbers in parsable (exact) values.) returns the epoch which is easily convertible in the full time including seconds.
root@truenas[~]# zfs get -p creation tank1/home@auto-hourly-20240717T180000:0200
NAME                                         PROPERTY  VALUE                  SOURCE
tank1/home@auto-hourly-20240717T180000:0200  creation  1721232000             -

